# How to fix it? i was get error

Tags: php

[29-Jul-2018 21:05:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: statusCode in /home2/postgram/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Utils.php on line 361
[29-Jul-2018 21:05:04 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: statusCode in /home2/postgram/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Utils.php on line 361
[29-Jul-2018 21:07:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: statusCode in /home2/postgram/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Utils.php on line 361
[29-Jul-2018 21:07:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: statusCode in /home2/postgram/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Utils.php on line 361

how to fix it?
this sc
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/master/src/Utils.php

Comment: I dunno.... define `$statusCode` before it is used  on line 361 maybe?

Comment: It is the same error, we'd only need to see it once. We don't need +1100 lines of code. Just post line 361, but more than likely the dup should resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0):

Code of function is:

```
public static function checkFFPROBE()
{
    // We only resolve this once per session and then cache the result.
    if (self::$ffprobeBin === null) {
        @exec('ffprobe -version 2>&1', $output, $statusCode);
        if ($statusCode === 0) {     // <-- line nr 361
            self::$ffprobeBin = 'ffprobe';
        } else {
            self::$ffprobeBin = false; // Nothing found!
        }
    }

    return self::$ffprobeBin;
}
```

You dont get error, it is just a php notice.
`exec()` as 3rd argument return status of the executed command (see more [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) )

I think, you can resolve it in 3 ways:

1. Declare `$statusCode` just before 361 line ( e.g. `$statusCode = null;` )
2. Change `exec()` to `shell_exec()` ( see more [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) )
3. You can ignore php notices by setting error reporting level `error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );`